# Math.round breaks only when I use number 100 in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a calorie calculator, i get all this variables by a post request for a form, and it all works fine, but mysteriously, when the variable peso (weight) is 100, the calorie calculations completely distorion itself.

Literaly the normal value of this calculation ranges between 1800-3500, everythings works fine until the variable peso is 100, then the end results becomes like 35642 or 28860.

JUST that number.An example Variable peso might be 99 and the end result is 3200, variable peso is 100 and the end result is like 34583, then variable peso is 101 and the reuslt is 3560 (normal again)

Form
https://www.trainerteamlift.com/encuesta-cals

Code

```
  var nombre = req.body.nombre;
  var edad = req.body.edad;
  var sexo = req.body.sexo;
  var email= req.body.email;
  var peso =req.body.peso;
  var altura = req.body.altura;
  var actividad = req.body.actividad;

  if (sexo == "5") {
    var tdee = ((9.99*peso + 6.25*altura - edad*4.25 + sexo) * actividad );
    var tdeeround = Math.floor(tdee*1);
  } else {
    var tdee = ((9.99*peso + 6.25*altura - edad*4.25 - sexo) * actividad );
    var tdeeround = Math.floor(tdee*1);
  };

  var tdeecut = Math.round(tdee*0.85);
  var tdeebulk = Math.round(tdee*1.15);
```

This are the inputs

```
<form action="/calc-calorias" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
        <label for="validationDefault03">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:160px !important" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor llene esta casilla')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
        <label for="validationDefault04">Pais</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:160px !important"   name="pais" placeholder="Pais" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor llene esta casilla')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mb-5">
        <label for="validationDefault05">Edad</label>
        <input type="number" style="width:60px !important"  name="edad" placeholder="Edad" min="12" max="100" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ingresa una edad válida')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 mb-5">
        <label>Sexo</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="sexo" required>

          <option value="5">Masculino</option>
          <option value="161">Femenino</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-1 mb-5">
        <label for="validationDefault03">Peso</label>
        <input style="width:80px" type="number" class="form-control" name="peso" placeholder="en kgs." min="1" max="300"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ingrese un peso válido en kilogramos')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required> kgs.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mb-5">
        <label for="validationDefault03">Altura</label>
        <input style="width:80px" type="number" class="form-control" name="altura" placeholder="en cm." min="120" max="260"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ingrese una altura válida en centimetros (Un metro veinte = 120)')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required> cms.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <label>Nivel de actividad</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="actividad" required>
          <option  value="1.2" selected> Sedentario - ejercicio prácticamente nulo</option>
          <option value="1.375" >Ligeramente activo - ejercicio/deporte 1-3 veces por semana </option>
          <option value="1.55" >Moderadamente activo - ejercicio/deporte 3-5 veces por semana</option>
          <option value="1.725" >Muy activo - ejercicio fuerte/deportes 5-7 veces por semana</option>
          <option value="1.9" >Super activo - ejericio muy fuerte/deportes 5-7 por semana o trabajo físico</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: What are the values you passed in the other variables? [Can't repro.](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lz1sywt/)

Comment: Please provide values for `peso`, `altura`, `edad`, `sexo`, and `actividad` that generates the value you expect, and then a set of values for all of those variables that generates the result you're not expecting, so we can try to reproduce the problem, please.

Comment: Perhaps  the problem is not about the weight variable ... If you add a string to a number using `+`, the number is converted to a string and concatenated with the string on the right hand side of `+`.  This means `number + sexo` performs string concatenation, not addition, multiplying the string representation  by 10 and adding 5.

Comment: @traktor53 since they're getting the value of inputs all their values are initially strings. But that would be a problem with any values.

Comment: @Kaiido  The background to my comment was that binary operators for multiplication, division and subtraction automatically convert both left and right string operands to  numbers. Combined with multiplication having higher priority than addition,  and left to right evaluation, all the calculations for `tdee` implicitly convert strings to numbers in a useful manner  - _except_ for the concatenation of "5" by the plus sign with the numeric partial result  on its left in the first branch of the `if` test.

Comment: @Kaiido ... like you I await the OP to post actual variable values that reproduce the problem in the manner claimed.

Comment: @Kaiido "sexo" is neither 5 or 161, "actividad" is from 1.2 to 1.725, but that numbers change and nothing happens until peso is 100

Comment: @traktor53 the code for the inputs are in the quesiton, I edited it

Comment: The added code does not help - it was already in the linked form page source code. Please add string values from the response that demonstrate the problem.